# MIN-DEQUEUE structure

Tags: algorithm, queue

I am learning about QUEUE implementation. I know how to implement Enqueue and Dequeue. I came across the term MIN-Dequeue (an abstract DS) today. I googled the exact term but couldn't find any links explaining what a MIN-DEQUEUE is, and the same in SO. Can anyone explain it to me how to design it?.

**My Idea:**
Extracting a minimum element from the queue = MIN-DEQUEUE. SO the minimum element must be at the front of the queue. So create a tree with minimum element at the top and so on.

**Quick Note:**
If this is a silly question please comment it so. I'll remove it.

Comment: You will have to explain what is a min deque. What are the operations it allows?

Comment: Is the MIN-DEQUEUE something better known as "priority queue"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: Sorry, I cannot explain it more, because I came across the term in a programming assignment, where I was tasked to structure it. It just said construct a MIN-DEQUEUE.

Comment: Was the term used to denote the whole data structure or just an operation?

Comment: My speculation is that this should be a structure that allows you to pop both the min and the max element and also allows push operation. Maybe I am wrong? @Henry also note that if I am right this is not simply a priority queue

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev He wrote 'MIN-DEQUE**UE**' and not 'min deque', like the `enqueue` and `dequeue` operations so it's highly likely that he means priority queue.

Comment: @svs good point. It could be that you are right, but I guess we'll never know unless OP finds a link to the original source

Answer (score 0):

MIN-Queue uses Min-Heap to store the data.You can write your own compactor function. 
By default in c++ STL if you use priority queue its by default a MIN-queue.